# Rotate Logs in a MongoDB Replica Set installed in Windows Server

Tags: mongodb

I have a Replica Set with 3 MongoDB installed in Windows 2012 Server by using a configuration file through Windows Services.

Here is my **mongod.cfg**

```
    storage:
       dbPath: E:\MongoDB\data
       journal:
            enabled: true
systemLog:
      destination: file
      path: E:\MongoDB\log\mongod.log
      logRotate: rename
      logAppend: false
      timeStampFormat: iso8601-local
```

From my understanding, by setting **logRotate** to rename and **logAppend** to false this should happen automatically. For my surprise it does not!

[Accordingly to MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/)

> MongoDB only rotates logs in response to the logRotate command, or when the mongod or mongos process receives a SIGUSR1 signal from the operating system.

After some digging, I found [this ticket opened](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7312) where it says that I should use a 3rd party tool to achieve it on Windows systems.

Is it the only way to rotate the logs on regular basis? And how would work in a Replica Set scenario?

Comment: I don't know windows, but I guess that it's same than in Unix.  In Unix, you move the file first to new name and then you give SIGUSR1 to mongod process (or mongos). That makes that, process closes logfile handle and opens new one.  In Unix you need to use "external" log rotate program too.

Comment: What SIGUSR1 will do behind the scenes? And how can I do it in Windows?

Comment: In Unix, even you move file to other name, as long as program have file handler open, it can keep writing to file. USR1-signal makes mongo{d/s} close-open that filehandler, so old file is freed and new file is created. I don't know how it is done in windows, but I guess that there is similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

Issuing the `logRotate: 1` admin command is the right way to do this, even in a replicaSet.

`db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })`

This can be done at midnight every day by creating a `.bat` file and creating a scheduled task to run it.

Sample batch file:

```
@echo off

set username=your_username
set password=your_password

mongo admin --username %username% --password %password% --eval "db.adminCommand({ logRotate: 1 })"
```

Add this to each server in the replicaset and they will rotate the logs without needing to restart, etc.

Example rotated log filenames:

```
mongod.log
mongod.log.2023-05-25T07-00-01
mongod.log.2023-05-26T07-00-01
```