# Will logRotate cause any unavailability in MongoDB service?

Tags: mongodb, logs

In another [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184941/rotate-logs-in-a-mongodb-replica-set-installed-in-windows-server), I've mentioned that how would I rotate logs in MongoDB Replica Set installed in Windows Server. However, it seems there's no built-in way to get it automatically on Windows - only with 3rd party tools.

That being said, I was wondering what would happen if I connect into MongoDB and execute

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

Will it cause any unavailability in MongoDB service? Or will be just a matter to stop log capture for couple seconds and start writing in the new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The should not be any break in service. Just remember set `systemLog.logRotate` or `--logRotate` to `rename` or it will open same file again...